# How to create a web page with the link like page.example.com

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, web

I am creating a website in 000webhost. If I purchase a domain ( for example www.example.com ), the index.html page opens when the user types the address in the URL bar. I want a specific page (for example page.html) to open when the user types page.example.com . How do I do that?

Comment: You might wanna check this out: https://www.000webhost.com/forum/t/how-to-create-sub-domain/46199/2

Comment: You only need to learn web programming and next, ask your doubts.

Comment: You apparently have no idea how a website works. You probably might read about that before creating your website.

Comment: I'm pretty good at making websites. It's just that I'm back after a long break. And somebody need not tell me what I'm supposed to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a the index.php with the following code:

```
<?php
  header("Location: page.html");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use redirects with a `.htaccess` file

[htacces redirect](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/215747748-How-can-I-redirect-and-rewrite-my-URLs-with-an-htaccess-file-)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, example.com domain is taken so u can't create sub domain like page.example.com.

suppose if example.com domain is yours, you can able to create a sub domain page.example.com using cpanel.

You registered your domain, signed up for a free 000webhost.com account, activated your account and am now trying to setup a subdomain for your blog like for example blog.yourdomain.com. Setting up the subdomain is a piece of cake really, all you need to do is to login to your 000webhost.com control panel, then click the Subdomains link and enter a name for your subdomain. The 000webhost.com servers will do the rest and create the necessary entires and directory on the server.
check Attachment
[image]